# Is it possible to track views of a model view, if the view is cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `PostsController` and my `Show` action, will be cached.

But, I want to record the number of times each post was viewed/loaded (i.e. how many times the `PostsController#Show` action was invoked.

If the router is always serving a cached file, how do I update the `post.view_count` counter_cache on every load? Is that even possible without breaking the functionality/purpose of caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use the Impressionist gem

https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist